# Error in converting date to int

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Employee bigint
DECLARE @StartDate date
DECLARE @EndDate date

SET @x = 'Select Distinct Att.Status
                ,ED.StartDate
                ,ED.EndDate
                ,u.FirstName
                ,u.Department
                ,ED.LeaveDays 
from EmployeeLeaveDetails ED
JOIN Employee e                 on ED.Employee = e.Employee 
                                and ED.IsDeleted = 0 
                                and e.IsDeleted = 0
JOIN Attendance a               on e.Employee = a.Employee
LEFT JOIN AttendanceStatus Att  on CAST(a.Status as nvarchar) = Att.Status  
                                and a.IsDeleted = 0 
                                and Att.IsDeleted = 0 
                                and Att.IsVacation = 1 
JOIN Users u                    on e.Users = u.Users 
                                and u.IsDeleted = 0
Where ED.Employee = ' +CAST(293 as nvarchar)+ ' 
                                and ED.StartDate = '+CAST('2016-01-01' as nvarchar)+' 
                                and ED.EndDate ='+CAST('2016-01-04' as nvarchar)+'
group by Att.Status 
        ,ED.StartDate
        ,ED.EndDate
        ,u.FirstName
        ,u.Department
        ,ED.LeaveDays'
```

Comment: this is my back end codeI am unable to Cast it,everytime it gives me "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" this error...Please help

Comment: I am newto stack overflow,please pardon me

Comment: can you post the table structure for the tables you used in this query?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines are the source of the error:

```
and ED.StartDate = '+CAST('2016-01-01' as nvarchar)+' 
and ED.EndDate ='+CAST('2016-01-04' as nvarchar)+'
```

In the final @x value, which is executed as sql, it will become

```
and ED.StartDate = 2016-01-01 
and ED.EndDate = 2016-01-04
```

2016-01-01 looks like a date to us, humans, but SQL Server sees a (calculated) integer: 2014 (2016 minus 1 minus 1).
Surround the dates with quotes like this (left out the CAST because I don't see why you should cast a date string to nvarchar).

```
and ED.StartDate = ''2016-01-01''' +' 
and ED.EndDate =''2016-01-04''' +'
```